# How to iterate skipping TypeError,AttributeError and IndexError in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup

I was trying to use BeautifulSoup to grab information from a wikipedia table. Now I am stacked because I cannot loop through an object.

This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_in_der_Europ%C3%A4ischen_Union_zugelassenen_Lebensmittelzusatzstoffe'
raw_data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(raw_data.content)
table= soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"})

for i in table:
    print i.contents[i].find_all("td")
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

If I use try: and except: than nothing would be printed.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are right, you can iterate over skipping `TypeError`, `AttributeError` and `IndexError` with handling exceptions, generally.

However the error here says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

and this error is caused by:

```
i.contents[i]
```

here `i` is not a integer, rather it's a beautifulsoup element tag. So with that you cannot index the list.

```
>>> type(i)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

So I believe you are trying to find all the `td` tags within it. Now when you are looping over the `table`, you have already selected the element. So, just doing `find_all` will give you all the `td` elements:

```
i.find_all("td")
```

So, your code should be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_in_der_Europ%C3%A4ischen_Union_zugelassenen_Lebensmittelzusatzstoffe'
raw_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data.content)
table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "wikitable sortable"})

for i in table:
    print i.find_all("td")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in table:
    print i.contents[i].find_all("td")
```

Here `i` is an element in the list - `table`; not an integer
we can't do `contents[i]`

You might want to try something like this,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_in_der_Europ%C3%A4ischen_Union_zugelassenen_Lebensmittelzusatzstoffe'
raw_data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(raw_data.content)
table= soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"})

for i in table:
    print i.find_all("td")
```

---

Here is the personalized answer following your way of doing it :-),

```
for i in table:
    for c in i.contents:
        try:print c.find_all("td")
        except:pass
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: if I do it manually like this: print table[0].contents[3].find_all("td")  than I can get the information.

Comment: Because here you are doing contents[3] and not contents[i]
'i' is not 1,2,3 but it is the element/tags in list/soup... You missing that :-)... And the reason you can't do contents is because if you check all the elements in i.contents you will also find strings like '\n' --- not a soup. So find_all wont work. Getting what I am saying?

Comment: table[0].contents has a length of 87 and I want to iterate through this. I expect that contents[i] would be 1,2,4...87

Comment: no, contents[0] would be first element. Here i is not zero, but i is table[0] which is a soup

Comment: OK now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: :-) Glad I could help. Appending the answer to follow your way

Comment: Pokemon catch all is really really bad advice.

Comment: I gave what he wants :-) And also have the better solution posted above. Its his will to practice and learn what he wants not ours :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
i.contents[i].find_all("td")
```

, exactly what are you expecting `i` to be? What are you expecting `i.contents` to be? Why would you expect to be able to use `i` itself as an index into `i.contents`?

You should probably go back and read the documentation more closely, and understand exactly what `soup.find_all` returns, so that you understand what the `i` values that you're iterating over will be.